# Replace each letter in a .txt with the letter six positions later

Tags: linux, replace, tr

I want to "encrypt" a .txt by replacing each letter with the letter six positions later. What I have right now is:

```
tr [:alpha:] ??? < myfile.txt
```

But I don't know what to put in ??? ...

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/19772/100397 for a possible inverse question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
tr '[a-z]' '[f-za-e]'
```

There's an explanation from the inverse question at [How does tr '[a-z]' '[n-za-m]' work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/19772/100397)

Comment: This worked, thanks. And also thanks to @roaima whose linked answer helped me understand the question better.